# Problem with Graphing Transformation of Cartesian coordinate into Polar coordinate.

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems, transformation, polar-coordinates

I was trying to map Rectangle from cartesian to polar coordinates.
I started by making a rectangle in a Cartesian Plane.
From the x and y coordinates of the rectangle, I calculate the radius and angle as follows 
$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$, $$\theta=tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}$$

After Tracing the point $(r,\theta)$

I got this curve shown in the image.

Is the Transformation Right? Or contain any Mistakes? 
The left one is Cartesian and Right one is Polar.
[image: tti]

Comment: Can you print the polar coordinates? It looks like your angle is never greater than $30^\circ$

Comment: Since the right-hand pane shows a polar plot, you should get exactly the same rectangle as the one you started with, so you’ve obviously made a mistake somewhere. For one thing, there should be a vertex at $\theta=\pi/4$, but all of the vertices in the polar plot are in $][0,\pi/6]$.